# English equivalent of 'Hoch sollst du leben'

Tags: idiom

To me the direct translation of this phrase `Hoch sollst du leben` is literally `High shall you live`. I've looked on dict.cc but the closest phrase I found was `Hoch soll er leben` which they said is the equivalent of `For he is a jolly good fellow`. I saw other translations that showed `Hail to thee`. Is there a more up to date English equivalent of the phrase?

Comment: In my view, "Hoch soll er leben" == "Hooray for [X]!"

Comment: Oder "three cheers for [X]!"

Comment: Instead of closing as off-topic wouldn't it make sense to migrate this to english.SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hoch soll er leben, hoch soll er leben, drei mal hoch.

That's a sung toast on a reasonable old birthday child / late bloomer / other somewhat murky occassions. Ages 60 and up, sung by his drinking buddies. Because of that

> For he's a jolly good fellow, for he's a jolly good fellow, which nobody can deny.

is quite accurate.

Comment: thanks. it just seemed `For he's a jolly good fellow` very antiquated.

Comment: How would you justify your judgement that this song is being used preferably for people aged 60+? In my experience, it is used for everybody able to intellectually process the wording.

Comment: Then I must be unable to process the wording because I stopped hearing it after I was about 8 years old...

Comment: @infinitezero  Perhaps I misunderstood Janka's answer? Does he mean "used **for** people 60+" or "used **by** poeple 60+"? (By "able to process the wording" I meant: not sung for babies prior to acquirement of speech.)

Comment: It's a rather old-fashioned toast, used by people born in the 1960ies and earlier.

Comment: I've heard it in a kindergarten recently...

Answer (score 1):

[Janka's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56022/833) offers the correct lyrics, but it's not the exact translation, since "he's a jolly good fellow" is a description while "hoch sollst Du leben" is more kind of a wish. Think of "Du sollst hochleben" instead, which is more related to "you shall be celebrated" (or cheered (up)on) though I guess there's some leeway to interpret the "hoch leben" as "have a great life".

Comment: We, experiencing ourselfs as internationally minded, usually sing: "High shall he liven, high shall he liven, three times high!"

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann reminds me of "I get my go stop over meadows" 

Comment: "Gehalt" als "go stop" - Aaaarrrggghhh!!!  -  I barrel it not!

Comment: @Volker  Thank you for the oversetting help, without would I not there with clear come.